# Sort a list with string and numbers

Tags: python

I need help to organize one list in python.
What I need is that:
I have a list like this: `[10,50,20,'STRING',5]`, i need organize this list, without move the string, like this: `[5,'STRING'10,20,50]`. is possible do this?
Thanks!

I need to create a linked list to check if has intersection in two strings, i check this at 'def Intersecao', the output need to be Ordered, and if the intersection was empty, i need to print the string 'VAZIO'.

```
    class No():
    def __init__(self, valor = None, proximo = None):
        self.valor = valor
        self.proximo = proximo

    def getValor(self):
        return self.valor

    def getProximo(self):
        return self.proximo

    def setProximo(self, novo_proximo):
        self.proximo = novo_proximo

class lista():
    def __init__(self, inicio = None):
        self.inicio = inicio

    def Inserir(self, valor):
        novo_no = No(valor)
        novo_no.setProximo(self.inicio)
        self.inicio = novo_no


    def Buscar(self, valor):
        dados = self.inicio
        while dados:
            if dados.getValor() == valor:
                return dados
            else:
                dados = dados.getProximo()
        return None


    def Intersecao (self, lista):
      no = self.inicio
      intersecao = []
      while no != None:
        if (not lista.Buscar(no.getValor())):
            no = no.getProximo()
        else:
            if(no.getValor() == ''):
                intersecao.append('VAZIO')
                no = no.getProximo()
            elif(no.getValor() in intersecao):
                no = no.getProximo()
            else:
                intersecao.append(no.getValor())
                no = no.getProximo()
      return intersecao

    def MostrarLista(self):
        lista = []
        dados = self.inicio
        while dados:
            lista.append(str(dados.getValor()))
            dados = dados.getProximo()
        print('->'.join(lista))

MyList = lista()
MySecondList = lista()
lista = []
lista2 = []

for i in range(40):
  dado = input()
  if i < 20:
    lista.append(dado)
  elif i >= 20:
    lista2.append(dado)

for i in lista:
    MyList.Inserir(i)

for i in lista2:
    MySecondList.Inserir(i)

listaOrdenada = []
for elementos in sorted(MyList.Intersecao(MySecondList)):
    print(elementos)
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: People are more likely to help if you show at least an attempt to solve the problem, opposed to wanting for someone to do the work for you, I'll give you a hint, get the 'STRING' index in the list, then pop the string, then sort the list, and finally re-insert the string to it's original index... now try to work it out.

Comment: What exactly is your criteria of sorting. Is it just numerical sorting? Furthermore, what did you try? Please show your own attempt at this and explain what difficulties you are having. StackOverflow is *not* a code writing service. It is a community that provides help for *explicit* programming problems. Show a [MCVE] of your issue.

Comment: I tried to use 'sorted', but the 'string' goes to the end, and is not what i want, the string need to be at the same position, only the numbers need to be organized.

Comment: @DouglasNickson edit your question and add your code, please.

Comment: @DouglasNickson Can the string be any string do you know what it's going to be?

Comment: I edit the post and post the code. :)

Comment: @A-B-B the string is always the same "VAZIO"

Comment: @idjaw post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question, if it is list only, one way to do is (*there might be better way though*):

```
# original list
my_list = [10,50,20,'STRING',5]

# Creating temporary list with all numbers in sorted order and reverse
# reversed such that we use pop() which is efficient in time complexity
sorted_list = sorted([element for element in my_list if not isinstance(element, str)], reverse=True)

# new list to append accordingly
new_list = []

# for each element if it is string then in new list it has same position as in original list
# else if it was originally number then, we append the respective sorted number 

for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
    if isinstance(element, str):
        new_list.append(element)
    else:
        new_list.append(sorted_list.pop())
new_list
```

Output:

```
[5, 10, 20, 'STRING', 50]
```

Or, it can be done with list comprehension which looks cleaner:

```
# Using list comprehension

my_list = [10,50,20,'STRING',5]
sorted_list = sorted([element for element in my_list if not isinstance(element, str)], reverse=True)

new_list = [element if isinstance(element, str) else sorted_list.pop() for index, element in enumerate(my_list)]
new_list
```

which gives same output.

Comment: I thought I could not move the "String" but needed ordering according to the position. For example, in this example the output was:

Original = [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 'EMPTY', 12, 11, 10]
New = [10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 'EMPTY', 18, 19, 20]

But the order must be:
[10, 11, 12, 'EMPTY', 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

My mistake, how can i do that?

Comment: Is input in reverse order always? what happens if input is `[0, 10, 2, 7,  'STRING', 5, 1]` ?

Comment: It's because i send my code to one software how will test my code, so he send the input and expect some outputs.

For exemple, the input is array1 = [2,4,3,6,7] and array2 = [2,3,6,7,8], i need to check the intersection at the two arrays, in this case the ouput need to be like this:
2
3
6
7
and if the intersection was empty i need to print the string "VAZIO", for exemplo:
array1 = [2,4,3,6,7, ''] and array2 = [2,3,6,7,8,''], the output need to be:
2
3
6
7
VAZIO

Comment: If order does not matter try `[i if not isinstance(i, str) else 'VAZIO'for i in set(array1).intersection(array2) ]`